# .NET 4 ObjectCache - Can We Hook Into a "Cache Expired" Event?

Tags: c#, caching, .net-4.0, objectcache

I've got a simple object being cached like this:

```
_myCache.Add(someKey, someObj, policy);
```

Where `_myCache` is declared as `ObjectCache` (but injected via DI as `MemoryCache.Default`), `someObj` is the object i'm adding, and `policy` is a `CacheItemPolicy`.

If i have a `CacheItemPolicy` like this:

```
var policy = new CacheItemPolicy 
{ 
   Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default, 
   SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
};
```

It means it will expire in 1 hour. Cool.

But what will happen is that unlucky first user after the hour will have to wait for the hit.

Is there any way i can hook into an "expired" event/delegate and manually refresh the cache?

I see there is a mention of `CacheEntryChangeMonitor` but can't find any meaninful doco/examples on how to utilize it in my example.

PS. I know i can use `CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable` and expire it manually, but i can't do that in my current example because the cached data is a bit too complicated (e.g i would need to "invalidate" in like 10 different places in my code).

Any ideas?

Comment: btw, no need to set Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default, since this Default value is set by default :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a property on the `CacheItemPolicy` called `RemovedCallback` which is of type: `CacheEntryRemovedCallback`. Not sure why they didn't go the standard event route, but that should do what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.removedcallback.aspx

Comment: Well, the link doesn't contain a code sample - in fact MSDN is very short on code samples for the runtime caching. I eventually figured it out, but you could have saved me an hour by providing an example.

Comment: [CodeProject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0) "Using MemoryCache in .NET 4.0"

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party with this one but I've just noticed an interesting difference between CacheItemUpdate and CacheItemRemove callbacks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemupdatereason.aspx

In particular this comment:

> Unlike the CacheItemRemovedReason enumeration, this enumeration does
>   not include the Removed or Underused values. Updateable cache items
>   are not removable and can thus never be automatically removed by
>   ASP.NET even if there is a need to free memory.

Comment: Even later to the party, but I've just noticed that you are referring to types in the `System.Web.Caching` namespace while the question is about the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace.

Comment: @StevenLiekens, they moved the caching to System.RunTime in .NET 4 as it was quite useful

Comment: You can still use `System.Web.Caching` in .NET 4 and up.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way to use `CacheRemovedCallback` event when cache expired.

I share for whom concern.

```
public static void SetObjectToCache<T>(string cacheItemName, T obj, long expireTime)
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

            var cachedObject = (T)cache[cacheItemName];

            if (cachedObject != null)
            {
                // remove it
                cache.Remove(cacheItemName);
            }

            CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy()
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMilliseconds(expireTime),
                RemovedCallback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(CacheRemovedCallback)
            };

            cachedObject = obj;
            cache.Set(cacheItemName, cachedObject, policy);
        }

public static void CacheRemovedCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
            {
                var configServerIpAddress = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.ConfigurationServerIpAddress();
                long configId = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.ConfigurationId();
                int userId = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.UserId();
                var tagInfoService = new TagInfoService();
                string returnCode = string.Empty;

                if (arguments.CacheItem.Key.Contains("DatatableTags_"))
                {
                    // do what's needed
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                    });
                }

            }
```